# Wildcard for CallbackPath on OAuthOptions in NetCore

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth

I was wondering if there there any way to specify a CallbackPath that allows for a wildcard place holder in the URL, like for example a tenant name

```
CallbackPath = new PathString(@"/*/Authentication/");
```

or as used we call it `tenantId` throughout our project

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "SignInCallback",
                //pattern: "signin/{tenantId}", WORKS
                pattern: "{tenantId}/Authentication/", DOES NOT WORK
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
                );
```

So I tried this

```
 CallbackPath = new PathString(@"/{tenantId}/Authentication/");
```

Both long shots really that did not work.

I don't absolutely need this but this is a new project and means we wouldn't need to migrate all the URL for our tenants to use `signin/` where it currently has `{tenantId}/Authentication/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the usage of `CallbackPath`.  The `CallbackPath` in the OpenID Connect middleware is internal path that are used for the authentication flow of the OpenID Connect protocol. That is used to identify the application's path after authenticate user from identity provider . You won't need to dynamically change the `CallbackPath` , it can be the same in a multi-tenant application . You can distinguish the tenant from tenant claim in JWT token , `CallbackPath` is internal url and it can't be used to redirect user to different areas/tenant in your application .

Comment: It explains why I cant find anything about that. So just for testing I removed anything to do with tenantId in the URL but I realised I need to use DI in `ExchangeCodeAsync` for `BackChannel` and the context does not hold anything that I can use to identify the tenant. It feels like THIS is the correct to go for all tenants instead I just don't know how to include the tenant name in  `OAuthCodeExchangeContext`

Comment: I need to know tenant because each tenant has its own secret for the BackChannel Challenge

Comment: The identity provider will issue tokens which include tenant id info , and in your application , you can use Oauth middleware events to trace the tenant info . Or after authentication , you can get tenant id from user claims and redirect user based on that

Comment: Thanks for info really appreciate it. I will need to spend some time to understand this process on my own. Hopefully I will get it sorted nicely.